# error: expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: c, loops

```
for(;a- > 64;)
```

I am receiving the following **error** in the above line:

> expected primary-expression before '>' token

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a simple `while` statement when there's no initialization or updating of the loop control: `while(a > 64)` is more easy to read.

Comment: Vote to close since it is unclear what the intended operation is and the OP has not responded to a request for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compile complains because

```
for(;a- > 64;)
```

is *invalid syntax*. Valid is (depends on what you are actually trying to achieve):

```
for(;a-- > 64;)
```

or

```
for(;a > 64;)
```

Comment: or even `for(;a --> 64;)`

Comment: @devnull: Which is nothing but my `for(;a-- > 64;)` written in confusing way :)

Comment: Absolutely, it's just another form for what you mentioned (but then the OP could have asked: what does this arrow `-->` operator do?)